# Request object not available in template tags in Django 1.11

Tags: django

I had been using Django 1.9 and now I am upgrading my code to 1.11
I had this template tag which worked fine in 1.9

```
@register.simple_tag
def active(request, pattern):
import re

pattern = "^" + pattern + "$"
#request = context['request']
if re.search(pattern, request.path):
    return 'active'

return ''
```

And my base.html

```
{% url "test:index" as home_url %}
<li class="{% active request home_url %}"><a href="{% url 'test:index' %}">Calendar</a></li>
```

But now an empty string is being passed instead of request object and so i am getting this error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'path'
```

This is the Templates settings I am using

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test', 'templates')],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/spare/local/projects/towerportal/apps/tower_common/decorators.py" in _fn
  42.             return t.render(context,request)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  203.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "/spare/local/projects/test/apps/portal/templatetags/active_util.py" in active
  12.     if re.search(pattern, request.path):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /caldb/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Here is the decorator that renders the views.

```
def render_view(template, with_print_view=False):
    def _decorator(view):
        @wraps(view)
        def _fn(request, *args, **kwargs):
            context = view(request, *args, **kwargs)

            # if view returns a response, return it
            if isinstance(context, HttpResponse):
                return context

            if with_print_view:
                if request.GET.get('print_view') == 'y':
                    context['original_template'] = template
                    return render(request, 'print_view.html', context)
                else:
                    context['show_print_button'] = True

            return render_to_response(template, context, RequestContext(request))

        return _fn

    return _decorator
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and the view that is failing.

Comment: All the views are being rendered by a decorator. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `render_to_response`, it's obsolete. In Django 1.10 the `context_instance` has been removed, so your code is equivalent to:

```
render_to_response(template, context=None, content_type=RequestContext(request))
```

You should use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead. Change the return line in your decorator to:

```
return render(request, template, context)
```

When you ran your code in Django 1.9, you should have got a deprecation warning about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `takes_context` flag on the template tag decorator.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def active(context, pattern):
     import re

     pattern = "^" + pattern + "$"
     request = context['request']
     if re.search(pattern, request.path):
         return 'active'
     return ''
```

[Here the docs reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

Comment: I'll have to change all my templates too and pass context object and that is not feasible, I want to pass only the request object.

Comment: I tried it but context object by default does not has the request in it

Comment: The template tag isn't the problem here, so changing `takes_context` to `True` won't help.

Comment: @Alasdair yes I read your answer, you're right. So the request is always passed to the simple tag as an argument and it also passed in the context?

Comment: No, the request is not always passed to the simple tag - the OP was explicitly passing it with `{% active request home_url %}`. It might be nicer to change the tag to `takes_context=True` and simplify the tag to ``{% active home_url %}`, but that is a separate issue to the error.

Comment: @Alasdair ah yes I see, didn't get attention to this. Thanks for the answer